# Run firebase emulators on github actions

Tags: firebase, unit-testing, continuous-integration, github-actions, firebase-tools

I'm trying to run my test on Github Actinos but after several attempts I was not able to do so.

Receiving

> Error: firestore: Firestore Emulator has exited because java is not installed, you can install it from https://openjdk.java.net/install/

---

```
  - name: Test
    uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v1.3.1
    env:
      JAVA_HOME: ${{ env.JAVA_HOME }}
      FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
      GCLOUD_PROJECT: ${{ secrets.nextGCLOUD_PROJECT }}
      PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.nextFIREBASE_PROJECTID }}
    with:
      args: |
        setup:emulators:firestore --debug
        firebase emulators:exec --debug --only functions,firestore \"npm run test --exit -- --forceExit --detectOpenHandles\"

  - name: Print debug logs
    if: failure()
    run: |
      java --version
      ls -la
      find . -type f -name "fire*-debug.log" | xargs cat
```

That's the output from action `name: Test`

```
/usr/bin/docker run --name d38e5ad93a422d456db01475acdae41155_521526 --label 3888d3 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e JAVA_HOME -e FIREBASE_TOKEN -e GCLOUD_PROJECT -e PROJECT_ID -e INPUT_ARGS -e HOME -e GITHUB_JOB -e GITHUB_REF -e GITHUB_SHA -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY -e GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER -e GITHUB_RUN_ID -e GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER -e GITHUB_ACTOR -e GITHUB_WORKFLOW -e GITHUB_HEAD_REF -e GITHUB_BASE_REF -e GITHUB_EVENT_NAME -e GITHUB_SERVER_URL -e GITHUB_API_URL -e GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL -e GITHUB_WORKSPACE -e GITHUB_ACTION -e GITHUB_EVENT_PATH -e RUNNER_OS -e RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE -e RUNNER_TEMP -e RUNNER_WORKSPACE -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL -e ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN -e ACTIONS_CACHE_URL -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true --network github_network_2107949b3a2c43d499d641b1c2f0fd12 -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/pwa/pwa":"/github/workspace" 3888d3:8e5ad93a422d456db01475acdae41155 setup:emulators:firestore --debug
firebase emulators:exec --debug --only functions,firestore \"npm run test --exit -- --forceExit --detectOpenHandles\"
setting firebase project to ***
Now using project ***
i  firestore: downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar... {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar..."}}

[2020-06-06T12:59:30.184Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[2020-06-06T12:59:30.186Z] > authorizing via FIREBASE_TOKEN environment variable
i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Starting emulators: functions, firestore"}}
[2020-06-06T12:59:30.217Z] [hub] writing locator at /tmp/hub-***.json
✔  functions: Using node@10 from host. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Using node@10 from host."}}
[2020-06-06T12:59:30.249Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId"}}
[2020-06-06T12:59:30.249Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download"}}
[2020-06-06T12:59:30.249Z] Starting Firestore Emulator with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Duser.language=en","-jar","/github/home/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar","--host","localhost","--port",8080,"--rules","/github/workspace/firestore.rules","--functions_emulator","localhost:5001"],"optionalArgs":["port","webchannel_port","host","rules","functions_emulator","seed_from_export"],"joinArgs":false} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Starting Firestore Emulator with command {\"binary\":\"java\",\"args\":[\"-Duser.language=en\",\"-jar\",\"/github/home/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar\",\"--host\",\"localhost\",\"--port\",8080,\"--rules\",\"/github/workspace/firestore.rules\",\"--functions_emulator\",\"localhost:5001\"],\"optionalArgs\":[\"port\",\"webchannel_port\",\"host\",\"rules\",\"functions_emulator\",\"seed_from_export\"],\"joinArgs\":false}"}}
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Firestore Emulator logging to \u001b[1mfirestore-debug.log\u001b[22m"}}

Error: firestore: Firestore Emulator has exited because java is not installed, you can install it from https://openjdk.java.net/install/
```

That's the output from action `name: Print debug logs`

```
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.289Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.291Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase setup:emulators:firestore --debug
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.292Z] CLI Version:   8.4.2
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.292Z] Platform:      linux
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.292Z] Node Version:  v10.21.0
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.292Z] Time:          Sat Jun 06 2020 12:59:27 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.293Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:27.293Z]
[info] i  firestore: downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar... {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"downloading cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar..."}}
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.168Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.170Z] Command:       /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/bin/firebase emulators:exec --debug --only functions,firestore npm run test --exit -- --forceExit --detectOpenHandles
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.171Z] CLI Version:   8.4.2
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.171Z] Platform:      linux
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.171Z] Node Version:  v10.21.0
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.171Z] Time:          Sat Jun 06 2020 12:59:30 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.171Z] ----------------------------------------------------------------------
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.171Z]
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.184Z] > command requires scopes: ["email","openid","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloudplatformprojects.readonly","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.186Z] > authorizing via FIREBASE_TOKEN environment variable
[info] i  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"hub"},"message":"Starting emulators: functions, firestore"}}
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.217Z] [hub] writing locator at /tmp/hub-***.json
[info] ✔  functions: Using node@10 from host. {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"functions"},"message":"Using node@10 from host."}}
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.249Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: projectId"}}
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.249Z] Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Ignoring unsupported arg: auto_download"}}
[debug] [2020-06-06T12:59:30.249Z] Starting Firestore Emulator with command {"binary":"java","args":["-Duser.language=en","-jar","/github/home/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar","--host","localhost","--port",8080,"--rules","/github/workspace/firestore.rules","--functions_emulator","localhost:5001"],"optionalArgs":["port","webchannel_port","host","rules","functions_emulator","seed_from_export"],"joinArgs":false} {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Starting Firestore Emulator with command {\"binary\":\"java\",\"args\":[\"-Duser.language=en\",\"-jar\",\"/github/home/.cache/firebase/emulators/cloud-firestore-emulator-v1.11.4.jar\",\"--host\",\"localhost\",\"--port\",8080,\"--rules\",\"/github/workspace/firestore.rules\",\"--functions_emulator\",\"localhost:5001\"],\"optionalArgs\":[\"port\",\"webchannel_port\",\"host\",\"rules\",\"functions_emulator\",\"seed_from_export\"],\"joinArgs\":false}"}}
[info] i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log {"metadata":{"emulator":{"name":"firestore"},"message":"Firestore Emulator logging to \u001b[1mfirestore-debug.log\u001b[22m"}}
[error]
[error] Error: firestore: Firestore Emulator has exited because java is not installed, you can install it from https://openjdk.java.net/install/
```

**How can I run my tests on Github Actions?**

Answer (score 9):

At the time of writing, the unofficial [firebase-action](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action) has recently added Java support. Unfortunately this is Java 7, and the emulator requires Java 8. (I have opened an [issue](https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/issues/70) in the repo to get this fixed).

Alternatively, for anyone that is interested, I have found the following to work well:

```
name: Test Firebase rules on PR
'on': pull_request
jobs:
  test_rules:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12'
      - run: npm install -g firebase-tools
      - run: npm ci
      - run: firebase emulators:exec --only firestore \"npm run test --exit\"
```

There are two important notes about the above workflow file:

1. `ubuntu-latest` is required as this contains both node and java.
2. `actions/setup-node@v1` is required to setup node to allow the install of global npm packages.

Also, if you would like to add a deploy step to the above you would only need to add this above the `setup-node` step, for authentication:

```
      - uses: google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@master
        with:
          project_id: ${{ secrets.GCP_PROJECT_ID }}
          service_account_key: ${{ secrets.GCP_SA_KEY }}
          export_default_credentials: true
```

(This is because the `export_default_credentials` will export the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable which firebase-tools will use for authentication).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need node environment, try this

```yaml
name: Test and coverage

on: [push, pull_request]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          fetch-depth: 2
      - uses: actions/setup-go@v2
        with:
          go-version: '1.19'
      - name: Install firebase
        run: curl -sL https://firebase.tools | bash
      - name: Run firebase emulators
        run: firebase emulators:start --only auth &
      - name: Run coverage
        run: go test -race -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode=atomic ./...
      - name: Upload coverage to Codecov
        uses: codecov/codecov-action@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.CODECOV_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me

```
jobs:
  test:
    name: Test
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: '12'
      - name: Install Dependacies
        run: cd functions && npm install
      - name: Test to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@master
        with:
          args: emulators:exec --only firestore \"cd functions && npm run test --exit\"
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```yaml
name: next

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Setting-up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2-beta
        with:
          node-version: '10'

      - name: Installing npm dependencies
        run: npm ci --prefer-offline --no-audit --progress=false

      - name: Checking-out
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Setting-up JAVA
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1.3.0
        with: 
          java-version: "12.x"

      - name: Setup and Test Emulator
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v1.3.1
        env:
          JAVA_HOME: ${{ env.JAVA_HOME }}
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
          GCLOUD_PROJECT: ${{ secrets.nextGCLOUD_PROJECT }}
          PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.nextFIREBASE_PROJECTID }}
        with:
          args: |
            setup:emulators:firestore
            emulators:exec --only firestore \"npm run test --exit\"
```

Comment: No.. this not work because the way that the action works.. `w9jds/firebase-action`

Comment: Error.. `sh: 2: emulators:exec: not found`

Comment: You can see why here... https://github.com/w9jds/firebase-action/blob/master/entrypoint.sh

Comment: try with splitting the args in my answer

Comment: I tried...  I had to add `firebase` before `emulator:exec` to work.. but still same problem...

https://jmp.sh/uGMlYHb

Comment: link of your repo ?

Comment: and also provide `firestore-debug.log` with the help of upload asset action

Comment: Hi, sorry I can't share the repo because it's private... but I added the logs on the question... that's helps ?

Comment: try with `master` branch, instead of v1.3.0 and give full log of the action from start till end, i think the issue is with environment vars not being set correctly

Comment: I tried, same problem.  I also tried to create my own Github Action... (https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-with-firebase-cli-and-java-ready)  but still ... same problem .   I don't know what else to do

Comment: any luck with this? struggling to find a working sample