# firebase functions emulators are failing to load in github action

Tags: firebase, github-actions

I'm trying to run a github action workflow which start firebase emulators,

It seems that for some reason the functions emulator fails to parse the `.runtimeconfig.json` ,I verified that it exits and valid.

Here is the error:
`functions: Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load function definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from function source: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'key')`

Here is an example of a .runtimeconfig.json:

```
{
  "coockie": {
    "key": "SOME_STRING"
  },
  "field": {
    "list": [
      "SOME_STRING"
    ]
  },
}
```

Here are some relevant steps from my workflow:

```
jobs:
  run-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout_Workflows
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up Node.js 16
        uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: 16.15.0
      - name: npm install -g firebase-tools-10.9.2
        run: npm install -g firebase-tools@10.9.2
      - name: npm install -g typescript-4.7.4
        run: npm install -g typescript@4.7.4
      - name: npm install firebase-functions
        run: cd firebase/cloud-functions && npm install
      - name: deploy serve & and run PlayWright
        run: npm run start:emulator
        shell: bash
        env:
          PROJECT_ID: MY_PROJRCT_ID
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: MY_FIREBASE_TOKEN
```

The NPM command do the following:

`"start:emulator": "cd firebase/cloud-functions; npm run start:automation"`

`"start:automation": "CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG=/home/runner/work/uvcamp/uvcamp/firebase/cloud-functions/.runtimeconfig.json firebase use dev && firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json  && firebase emulators:exec --import=./emulator-data --only=auth,firestore,functions,storage \"npm run start:playwright-test\"",`

I ran the same project locally and it worked find with no problems, including the script in `npm run start:playwright-test`

I tried setting an environment variable `CLOUD_RUNTIME_CONFIG` with the absolute path and to downgrade version of:

- firebase-tools to 10.9.2
- typescript to 4.7.4

and still got the same error.

any thought on what can be the issue?

thank!

Comment: What would be the use case for starting the emulators in the GitHub workflow?

Comment: I use the emulators for tests automation

Comment: It seems like someone has made something that worked here. I haven't tested it https://stackoverflow.com/a/66532823/11267494